# Direct initialization of a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I have:

```
struct date
{
int day;
int month;
int year;
};

struct person {
char name[25];
struct date birthday;
};


struct date d = { 1, 1, 1990 };
```

Initialization with

```
struct person p1 = { "John Doe", { 1, 1, 1990 }};
```

works.

But if I try

```
struct person p2 = { "Jane Doe", d};
```

I get an error like:

"Date can't be converted to int".

Whats wrong? d is a struct date and the second parameter should be a struct date as well. So it should work. Thanks and regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [C structure initialization with variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700878/c-structure-initialization-with-variable)

Answer (score 7):

```
struct person p2 = { "Jane Doe", d};
```

It can be declared this way only if the declaration is at block scope. At file scope, you need constant initializers (`d` is an object and the value of an object is not a constant expression in C).

The reason for this is that an object declared at file-scope without storage-class specifier has static storage duration and C says:

> (C11, 6.7.9p4) "All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals."

At block-scope without storage class specifier, the object has automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I would suggest that to try :) 

struct person

{

  float salary;

  int age;

  char name[20];

};

int main(){

struct person person1={21,25000.00,"Rakibuz"};

 printf("person name: %s  \n",person1.name);

 printf("person age: %d\n",person1.age);

 printf("person salary: %f\n",person1.salary);


}
```